# Modern components to change old Soviet ones to make ion generator

Tags: components, function-generator, alternatives

I am trying to make the same scheme to get an ion generator. I found this one on the Internet and have difficulties finding the components in Europe as I cannot find their names in English. Can anybody help me find their names to look up in the shops or if you know any source which will help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: And if you're asking for someone to suggest alternatives then at least type out a list of the components you can't figure out. Make it easy for your reader. We won't be suggesting places to buy them as shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: I built the given scheme back in my country as I had all the necessary components. As I am rn in Europe and I need to find the components I wanna know if there is a chance of finding exactly these components

Comment: Youtuber BigClive is a big ionizer fan, he shows several much simpler designs in his videos and uses common components. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/c/Bigclive/search?query=ionizer

Comment: @Dea of all continents, I'd assume the likelihood of being in Europe in a place where it's impossible to get components are slimmest - what specifically can you not easily source via the usual online distributors?

Comment: Newark and RS Components have big operations in Europe, right? They should be able to supply you with whatever you need--this circuit isn't anything special and common everyday transistors and diodes should be fine replacements for the ones you can't get.

Comment: @Hearth And Digi-Key ships all over the world…

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the following:

- Step-down transformer 18 to 20V AC out with two full-wave bridges, one for the generator and one for the fan. Max unloaded output about 27V DC for each one. This should be easy.
- Zener shunt regulator for the inverter supply. Not sure of its voltage. Perhaps 15V? (update: @AVK says 18V)
- Royer-type oscillator driving the inverter transformer primary pair. Frequency? Simulate it to get an idea.
- Inverter step-up transformer with center tap primary. Turns ratio? Inductance? Hi-pot voltage? This is the tricky part.
- Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier on the secondary, protected with a spark gap to prevent overvoltage to the diode. Target Voltage? Spark gap limit? Depends on the step-up transformer. The caps are 470pF, 6.3kV (the character is Cyrillic '**п**', which corresponds to Latin 'p'). The diodes are probably 1N4006 (800V) ot 1N4007 (1kV) type. So I'd guess a spark gap limit of 300-500V.
- DC fan circuit with a janky shunt regulator. It's a dumb circuit, but do-able. Zener is 12V, so a cheesy adaptation for a 12V fan.

The transistor part numbers for the Royer and inverter driver pair are given and seem to be Toshiba, so you could locate them and cross them if needed. (Update: @AVK notes the Soviet part numbers.)

That leaves the step-up transformer as the biggest variable. It not only needs the right turns ratio and inductance, it also has to be able to withstand the high secondary (hi-pot) voltage so that it doesn't arc over to the primary. Perhaps a 240V line-in step-down with 24V center tap could work - connected in reverse to make a step-up.

Followup: I tried simulating the oscillator by itself with 300pF caps. It doesn’t seem stable. The design might count on interacting with ripple kicked back from the driver PNP pair. I’d scrap it and just use a 555, and for the drivers use NPN or N-fets on the low side instead of PNP like shown.

With further fiddling and messing with the transformer parameters I was able to simulate a 2.7kV output.

Answer (score 1):

Д815Ж is an old Soviet power Zener diode (18V, 8W). There is a company that sells them at retail: https://www.chipdip.ru/product/d815zh. Delivery, however, is only available to Russia, Armenia, Kazakhstan, Belarus and Kyrgyzstan. It might be better to replace it with a linear voltage regulator.

КТ315Б are just ordinary npn transistors. They can be replaced with, for example, 2sc945.

КТ816Б is a 45V 3A 25W pnp transistor.

The original article says that the voltage at the output of the transformer T2 should be 2-3 kV.

КЦ106Г are 10kV 10mA rectifiers.

Hope this helps

Comment: Didn’t see the ‘Б’ on the transistor numbers, good catch. How about the inverter transformer?

Comment: The coils I and II should have 25 turns of 0.35 mm wire.